# Keep Backstage software-templates up to date with parent

Tags: git, github, backstage

I am using [Backstage software templates](https://backstage.io/docs/features/software-templates/) to render repos based on some input.

How do I keep these up to date with the parent repo in the best way.

Example, my template has a setting.yml file and a src/ directory. The users of my template can modify src, and I the settings.yml file.

```
src/
settings.yml
```

The settings.yml file may look something like

```
apiVersion: backstage.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: ${{values.name}}
  description: ${{values.description}}
```

If I make a change in the settings.yml, how do I best push that out to all the templates?
Preferably I would like to open a PR with the changes.

Will it be a different approach if I add a static change or a change that needs rendering?

```
id: ${{values.id}}
```

vs.

```
id: 123
```